# Trigger Update Asset Index from url endpoint

Tags: assets, reindex

Is it possible to trigger an update of the asset indices from an url endpoint? I guess not, but is it planned to provide some kind of API?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this or writing anything for this @larsbilke?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not natively, but you could easily write a [plugin](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction) with a [controller](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers) that exposes the [AssetIndexingService](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/AssetIndexingService).